# Swift Package - How to exclude files in root git directory from the actual Swift Package?

Tags: swift, swift-package-manager, swift-package

I am creating a Swift Package that is essentially a wrapper for multiple XCFrameworks generated from Objective-C frameworks so they can be installed via SPM.

Everything works fine as far as creating the SP and ability to add it as a dependency to an app. But I have a bunch non-essential files included in the SP's repository that I don't want to include in the actual SP - *i.e. They shouldn't show up in Xcode's navigator when the SP is added as a dependency.*
*(These consist of the source Obj-C Frameworks, README, Changelog, Xcode Workspace for demo app, Script files for generating the XCFrameworks, etc)*.

Is this even possible?
Or will SPM always checkout the entire repo and make all files visible to the user?

I have tried using various permutations of the `Target` specifiers: `source, path, exclude` but to no avail.

Here is the closest I can get with a valid manifest, but when I check out the SP in a dummy Xcode app, I can still see all the files from the repo included:

```
// swift-tools-version:5.3
// The swift-tools-version declares the minimum version of Swift required to build this package.

import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "WrapperSwiftPackage",
    platforms: [.iOS(.v13)],
    products: [
        .library(name: "WrapperSwiftPackage", targets: ["WrapperSwiftPackage"])
    ],
    dependencies: [],
    targets: [
        .target(
            name: "WrapperSwiftPackage",
            dependencies: [
                "ObjCFramework1",
                "ObjCFramework2"
            ],
            path: "", // Set to root directory so we can exclude files below
            exclude: [
                "CHANGELOG.md",
                "Dangerfile.swift",
                "README.md",
                "Workspace.xcworkspace",
                "Scripts/generate-xcframework.sh",
                "Scripts/link_git_hooks.sh",
                "Objective-C Frameworks/"
            ],
            sources: [
                "Sources/WrapperSwiftPackage/main.swift",
                "XCFrameworks/ObjCFramework1.xcframework",
                "XCFrameworks/ObjCFramework2.xcframework"
            ]
        ),
        .binaryTarget(name: "ObjCFramework1", path: "XCFrameworks/ObjCFramework1.xcframework"),
        .binaryTarget(name: "ObjCFramework2", path: "XCFrameworks/ObjCFramework2.xcframework")
    ]
)
```

Answer (score 12):

Not sure if that isn't a bug though, but I've accidentaly came up to one solution for this.

If you put an empty Package.swift (I mean, one like this):

```
// swift-tools-version:5.5

import PackageDescription

let package = Package()
```

into one of project subfolders, then even though SPM is checking the subfolder out, it's excluded from Xcode navigator, and thus, from the project visibility.

I would like to know if that's a bug or is it documented somewhere, every hint is appreciated.

Works with local and remote dependencies.

Comment: Tried in Xcode 14.3.1 to strip out an example project in an SPM. But doesn't work. Have you found any other solutions?

Comment: Another link suggested to only use a file containing `import PackageDescription`. Not sure if it was this change, or a clean. But one of those worked. Thanks